# Amplify Graphql list only current user Todo's

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

Having a schema.graphql like this one:

```
type Todo @model @auth(rules: [
  {
    allow: owner,
    operations: [create, read, update, delete],
    identityClaim: "sub"
  }
]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  owner: String
}
```

I have cognito for athentication working on my test app. I can create users, log in as one of them, etc.

What doeas @auth directive exactly? When I use my listTodos query:

```
const todoData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listTodos));
```

I expect to have back from the server **only** my todos, but I got all of them. Obviously I'm missing something out.

I mean, If I view my table data, the owner field is correctly popullated with my user's ID.

How do I accomplish my use case? Listing only my items

Comment: Don't you need to have the identityProvider as "oidc" in order to use the identityClaim "sub"?

Comment: I tried without it with the same result

Comment: There is an example here: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#custom-claims

Comment: @Chux did you find a solution? I'm in the same trouble...

Comment: @fabik111 I don't remember, but I ended up not using AWS

Comment: @Chux Thank you.  BTW I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66176876/17913726)

Comment: @fabik111 that's weird. In the docs you can read "Amplify.DataStore.clear() provides a way for you to clear all local data if needed" and this was a graphql query. Anyway, I'm glad you solved it.