# Amplify.DataStore.query is returning data created by all users, instead of owner only

Tags: android, aws-amplify

When I run a query, I am getting data from all the users (owners), not just the currently logged in owner. I thought that if I had this: [create, update, delete, read] only owners could read their data? What's going on here? What am I missing?

I am using the same device (emulator), and I sign in and sign out with different accounts.

```
Amplify.DataStore.query(Todo.class,
        all -> {
            while (all.hasNext()) {
                Todo todo1 = all.next();
                Log.i("tag", "Title: " + todo1.getName());
            }
        },
        failure -> Log.e("tag", "Query failed.", failure)
);


type Todo
@model
@auth(
  rules: [
    {
      allow: owner,
      ownerField: "owner",
      operations: [create, update, delete, read]
    }
  ]
) {
  id: ID!
  owner: String
  name: String!
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the solution here:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/sync/q/platform/android#update-and-delete-with-predicate

Every time you switch user on the same device, you have to call Amplify.DataStore.clear()

> Note: In case multiple users share the same device and your schema
> defines user-specific data, make sure you call
> Amplify.DataStore.clear() when switching users. Visit Auth events for
> all authentication related events.